# executing shell from command in Yii

Tags: php, terminal, yii

The book I'm using to learn Yii, is telling me that we're going to use the yiic shell command to invoke other commands.

To use yiic shell, it's telling me

```
cd /Webroot/demo
```

So I moved into my demo folder, which is inside htdocs on my MAMP setup. See first image below.

It is then telling me, from within my demo folder, to execute this

```
  YiiRoot/framework/yiic shell
```

where it defines the `YiiRoot` as "the folder where I have installed Yii". In my set up, I believe YiiRoot is htdocs. See image 2 below.

so, from within demo folder,  I tried running

```
htdocs/framework/yiic shell
```

and also

```
/htdocs/framework/yiic shell
```

but in both cases I get "no such file or directory"

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

**Demo** and **Framework** inside htdocs

[image: demo in htdocs]

Yiic Inside **Framework**

[image: Yiic inframework]

Comment: I believe you can't award a bounty until the question has been live for 48 hours.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For linux-like filesystem.
Run next commands

```
cd /htdocs/demo/
./protected/yiic shell index.php
```

Please notice that probably your also need to set execution permission for yiic file

```
chmod +x /htdocs/demo/protected/yiic
```

Answer (score 0):

It didn't work because the shell has been deprecated and it needs to be done with Gii